# SO jobs - where to ask?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

NOTE: I know this is off topic, but can you tell me where can I ask this question?

I have submitted my CV to  this link, when it was still active:[remote SO job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/203933/qa-test-engineer-remote-compucorp-ltd.)

I was told that I have to complete the tasks by 31th October. Now, when I try to go to personalised response form: [link](https://www.compucorp.co.uk/node/2114?cid1=9177&cs=db87f86fdcc76ee22bc91bae2762de08_1539850802_168), it says access denied.

How to be able to submit the tasks to them? I have tried sending them an email, but they are still not responding.

Comment: You can email or telephone the company directly. How to do this is an exercise in patience and diplomacy which most of us get wrong from time to time, and that probably requires a book or two to answer.

Comment: My advice is that if a company requires you to do a technical test or a challenge, don't spend more time on it than you are willing to waste. For me, if the job is a good fit, then I'd spend an hour or two - but more than that is too much of a risk. I learned the hard way after doing a 12 hour programming/documentation task many years ago - for a famous and well regarded London outfit - and not getting anything more than a pro-forma reply for my trouble.

Comment: Finally, getting a job is a numbers game. If you have five hours to spare, make five applications with reasonable care, rather than one application that is exceedingly polished.